# JavaScript Intellisense in Visual Studio 2017 RC

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-2017, javascript-intellisense

Today i have installed Visual Studio 2017 RC to try out the new features

I am on a ASP.net web forms project.I was trying to check the new JavaScript Intellisense as they promoting it like it .Found no Intellisense at all or support for guessing jQuery stuff or auto completion

Am I missing something here????

Comment: Can you give an example of what's not working as expected?  Also, it would be appropriate to file feedback to VS about this.

Comment: @Jimmy i have opened one of my existing files contains jQuery methods and other JS related and i saw on the videos displaying the new Intellisense features in JS that the jQuery methods and declarations will be available inside VS without the need to go to check the jQuery documentation ...which i didn't see ...please note that i am running this 2017 rc version side by side with 2015... the message i am getting when i type the $ sign is "Intellisense is unable to determine the accuracy of this completion term"

Comment: Please send in this feedback so someone on the JavaScript Language team can look into the issue.

Comment: done

this is what i got from VS Team


Solution by Ed Maurer (PEAK PERFORMANCE)2/2/2017, 3:17:00 AM
JavaScript Intellisense is not extensible in VS 2017 as it was in previous releases. We've replaced the existing JavaScript editing infrastructure in this release and now library API intellisense is provided by TypeScript definition files (.d.ts). An overview of the new editing infrastructure is here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Salsa-Preview-in-Visual-Studio-15-Preview

Comment: @KhaledAhmed, could you please share this feedback from VS Team Solution as a reply when you have free time, it will help other community members who meet the same or similar issue to know it, thanks :)